# How to pass array of string as parameter to function in WSDL webservice from Android?

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, webservice-client, android-ksoap2

I am using WSDL web service which has a method accepting a string array as an argument. I have tried ksoap2 library but unable to find out how to pass array as an argument to that method. There are options to add parameter,values but my webservice require as an argument to function not as separate parameter,values.
We can also use simple HTTP client and send a soap request as well. But I am unable to build that exact soap request for wsdl which will take array of strings as argument.

Is there any way I can build that SOAP request ? Array is of type string of size 2.

Comment: The webservice is on Php server. Also have tried using SOAP UI tool but unable to find option to add string array as argument. Does Pro version have this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you debug your WebService it will show you example Soap Request and Response formats.  Copy those examples and in your Java handle the assigning of the values to that string.